# Joomla asynchronous script loading jdoc head

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous, joomla

I am using Joomla! 3.4

`<jdoc:include type="head">` calls the `head.php` file in `/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/`, where a reference to `$strAttr['async']` can be found in the part to generate the script file links.

`$strAttr` is just the array as named by the foreach loop, but this comes from `$document->_scripts`.

**I want to load my scripts asynchronously**, how can I change the attribute `$strAttr['async']` for each script file? I know I can just change the code in `head.php` but I think I am overlooking some setting in Joomla.

Comment: Hey there. I restructured your question a bit to state context from the start, and improved lightly the code formatting. Do not hesitate to put some bold somewhere, I wasn't sure where the synchronous part would get in the question. Good luck with your question! You could add here the part of the renderer which generates the script file links to help readers help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this operation for each script file you have to write a system plugin and implement the function `onBeforeCompileHead()`.

In this function you need something like that:

```php
/**
 * possible implementation of onBeforeCompileHead
 * to make all the scripts async.
 */
public function onBeforeCompileHead() {

    $document = JFactory::getDocument();

    foreach ($document->_scripts => $url) {
        $document->_scripts[$url]['async'] = true;
    }
}
```

Instead if you want just make the js of your application or of your template use JDocument::addScript(); like that :

```php
/**
 * Possible implementation to insert a async script in a component or a module. 
 * @see JDocument::addScript($url, $type = "text/javascript", $defer = false, $async = false)
 */
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js', "text/javascript", false, true);
```